# SELinux set enforcing issue

Tags: centos6, selinux

I am on CentOS 6.9 with a LAMP stack, trying to set SELinux=enforcing in `/etc/selinux/config` 
However after **reboot ** and checking `sestatus` I still get `SELinux status:disabled`
Then I tried running `setenforce Permissive` which returns `setenforce: SELinux is disabled`
Also `setsebool httpd_can_sendmail 1` which returns the same msg

I verified the link between `ln -s /etc/selinux/config /etc/sysconfig/selinux`
contents of config file:

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.
SELINUX=enforcing

# SELINUXTYPE= type of policy in use. Possible values are:
#       targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
#       strict - Full SELinux protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

Why are commands not working?  How can I enable SELinux?

edit,  the reason why I am trying to enable SELinux is because of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341678/php-mail-function-not-working-on-centos-server

outout from `cat /proc/cmdline`

```
ro root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00 rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup00/LogVol01 rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup00/LogVol00  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us crashkernel=129M@48M rhgb quiet rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet vga=791
```

Comment: linux cloud from 1and 1

Comment: Oh, it's a virtual machine? OK, please run `virt-what` and post the output. If it is not installed you can install it with `yum install virt-what`. This will tell us the hypervisor type that is being used, which is important. Some do not allow for SELinux to be run.

Comment: virt-what: vmware

Comment: That's really strange. VMware certainly allows for SELinux to run.

Comment: Please post the output of `cat /proc/cmdline`